Using the filters “fromdate” and “todate” on the /badges API endpoint has no effect
It looks like the fromdate and todate filters have no effect on the /badges endpoint:
Example without these filters:
https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/badges#page=1&pagesize=30&order=desc&sort=rank&filter=default&site=drones&run=true
Example with these filters:
https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/badges#page=1&pagesize=30&fromdate=2024-09-27&todate=2024-09-29&order=desc&sort=rank&filter=default&site=drones&run=true
The resulting JSON are identical.
Even if we set these filters in the year 2044 the output is the same:
https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/badges#page=1&pagesize=30&fromdate=2044-09-27&todate=2044-09-29&order=desc&sort=rank&filter=default&site=drones&run=true
The documentation about the dates doesn't give more explanation.
So, are these filters supported on this endpoint? Or are they simply ignored? Then why the Try It function shows them?

You are correct, they are ignored. The list of badges itself does not have dates to filter on (and if the code attempted to filter on them, you'd be getting errors because they don't exist). They shouldn't be displayed on that page.

Thanks for the answer. What is the next step? Add the [status-review] tag?

I could, but tbh, this is super low priority (nobody has even noticed it for the many years that those have been listed there) and will probably sit in a backlog for eternity until API v3 replaces the existing v2.3 someday. I'm fine just having a question on Meta documenting that they do nothing if anyone else ever questions it.

Fair enough, the API is broken since 1 month and SE didn't fix it, so the API playground will be even less prioritized.
